# Is there a way to squash evolutions in the Play framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

What is the recommended way to manage evolutions in Play, when the number of evolution scripts becomes one too many? Is it recommended practice to squash evolutions into a single file, say 1.sql, and continue on from there? Or should I just live with multiple scripts?

Comment: What do you mean "becomes one too many" ?

Comment: I meant to ask how one should manage evolution scripts when there are too many scripts. In my case, I already have about 30 scripts, like 1.sql, 2.sql... 30.sql.